# Best MySQL Backup Tool/Scheduler for Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mysql

Recommend a good tool. It doesnt have to be packed full of features, it just needs to be reliable. Though both would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump is the right tool for you, just make a script and just schedule it.

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --all-databases > mybackup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

[www.mysqlbackuptool.com](http://www.mysqlbackuptool.com) I made it and use it on MS server 2003